# Format list of Dictionaries in yaml using reumal.yaml python

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

When i dump my yaml data using yaml.dump(stream_data)

I'm getting below output

```
models:
 - model: "a"
   type: "x"
   groups:[]
   #bunch of properties...
 - model: "b"
   type: "y"
   groups: []
   #bunch of properties...
```

desired output:

```
models:
 - { model: "a", type: "x", groups:[]}
 - { model: "b", type: "y", groups: []}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is two level of flow-style nodes and in ruamel.yaml the only way
to create that is force flow-style on the nested dicts:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

def flow_dict(**kw):
    result = ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap(**kw)
    result.fa.set_flow_style()
    return result

data = dict(models=[flow_dict(model='a', type='x', groups=[]), flow_dict(model='b', type='y', groups=[])])

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.indent(sequence=4, offset=2)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
models:
  - {model: a, type: x, groups: []}
  - {model: b, type: y, groups: []}
```

There is no way (apart from post-processing the output stream), to get the space between `{` and the `model` key.